# Php to echo returned value from javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using the function `getAddress()` to get the address of the coordinates provided. How do I make sure that the returned value of the function could be echoed in php?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=yourAPIkey"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetAddress(lat,lng) {
        var lat = parseFloat(lat);
        var lng = parseFloat(lng);
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    var addr = results[0].formatted_address;
                    return addr;
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<?php

    $lng = 103.72;
    $lat = 1.34628;
    echo    "<script type='text/javascript'>",
                  "GetAddress(",$lat,",",$lng,");",
            "</script>";

?>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding the relationship between PHP and Javascript

Comment: @PatrickQ What am in misunderstanding? Issit the link?

Comment: PHP cannot "call" Javascript. Therefore, your Javascript function cannot "return" a value to PHP the way you are asking for. The PHP has already finished execution by the time any of the HTML/Javascript is processed.

Comment: @PatrickQ So there's no way I could get the value from php?

Comment: You need to do a better job explaining what it is you're actually trying to accomplish. Why does PHP need the result of this function? Unless you have more that you're not showing, you don't have any PHP code that would make use of this value. Either you actually want to use this value in Javascript and just don't know it, or you want to generate the value client-side and then use ajax to send the value to the server.

Comment: It almost sounds like you are trying to execute javascript within php (no no). You may have better luck with this library: http://geocoder-php.org/

Comment: There is a php page actually, the coordinates are to be retrieved from a database, all done in .php, but for this code I'm giving it values for the coordinates to make it simpler. The php page is supposed to have other information too, but all is fine, except this part. So I'm using reverse geolocation as a function in javascript, then I want to display the result with the rest of info I retrieved all together in one page. But for now, if I use alert(addr) instead of return addr in the function, it does pop out the address, so the problem is really with the return part.

Comment: Are you trying to display the output from the function call to `GetAddress()` on the php script that rendered the call?

Comment: That's because, as I said before, you _cannot return from JS to PHP_. To be honest, I'm not sure why you're involving Javascript at all. It seems like everything you're trying to do is contained in your PHP script. Just because you happened to find a Javascript geocoder doesn't mean it's appropriate for what you're doing.

Comment: @Latheesan Yess

Comment: @Tyra see my answer.

Comment: @PatrickQ I see, thanks for the heads up! Learned something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all that you are trying to do is write the output from the function call (as per your recent comment reply), you can just do this:

```
$lng = 103.72;
$lat = 1.34628;

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.write(GetAddress(",$lat,",",$lng,"));</script>";
```

So, where ever the `GetAddress` is called, you'll see the output.

Alternatively, if you need to target a specific area where you want the result to appear, see `Zakaria Acharki` updated answer.

---

I personally would avoid mixing php and javascript and just do everything in php.

For example;

```
<?php

// Config
define('API_KEY', 'yourAPIkey');

// Helper function to geodecode lat/lng
function getFormattedAddress($lat, $lng) {
    $result = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=". API_KEY ."&latlng=$lat,$lng"));
    if ($result->status == 'OK') {
        return $result->results[0]->formatted_address;
    }
    return 'Invalid lat/lng coordinates'; 
}

// Usage
$lat = 40.714224;
$lng = -73.961452;
echo getFormattedAddress($lat, $lng);

?>
```

Outputs: `277 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA`

So, your php script has the `lat`, `lng` coords, so you can just call the php function and just render the result in one go.

P.S. you should avoid posting your API keys in your question; people might misuse it ;)

Answer (score 8):

The `echo` that you've will echo the JS script to your page and not the result so I suggest to you to add a result container then put the data inside it like :

```
<?php

    $lng = 103.72;
    $lat = 1.34628;

    echo "<p id='result'> </p>";

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>".
            "document.getElementById('result').innerText = GetAddress(".$lat.",".$lng.");".
         "</script>";
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't print out

Comment: Actually, the comma works in this case. It is seen as the separator in the list of strings passed to `echo` http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9b6e0050e842c559293a41ecde07b87b84f61a43

Comment: Later how could I obtain `result` as a variable, could I use it as `$result`? @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: Your approach does not work if javaScript function is `async`. On JavaScript I am doing async call which does not wait to return the return value in `async` call into result variable that causes to return `undefined` output @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: Please the following link for more detail (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767801/how-to-assign-a-asynchronous-javascript-functions-output-to-a-variable-from-php).  @ZakariaAcharki